# ArrayAdapter in Android

Tags: android

```
ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource);
```

The second parameter of `ArrayAdapter` is int type but we pass the layout as the second parameter in `ArrayAdapter` and the Layout component is the type of View.

So how the `ArrayAdapter` change the type View to int ?

Comment: Actually it is id of layout in background it's inflated and converted to view.

Comment: Its the Layout's Resource ID. Its not a normal integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I totally acknowledgement your question, and this question is likely to come in mind in the initial phase of Android Development.
When you pass Layout as the second parameter in the ArrayAdapter, for ex `(context,R.layout.some_layout)` you are not actually passing the layout but you are passing the reference of the layout to the method. As the second parameter is `R.layout.some_layout` so this actually is the reference of the layout which you are passing and this is stored as Integer Value in R file in your project.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in Document ..

> context   Context: The current context.This value must never be null.
>
> resource  int: The resource ID for a layout file containing a layout to
>   use when instantiating views.
>
> textViewResourceId    int: The id of the TextView within the layout
>   resource to be populated

```
ArrayAdapter<String> itemsAdapter =  new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
```

So . `int resource` is a Id of your layout file . you are not passing view to it . you are passing the Id of the view .

Answer (score 0):

You should use a different `ArrayAdapter` constructor to change the view type:

```
ArrayAdapter(Context context, int layoutResource, int dataResource);
```

Example:

```
final ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter(context, R.layout.layout_resource, R.array.data_resource);
```

Where `R.layout.layout_resource` and `R.array.data_resource` are of type `int` and reference to your resources layout view and resources data. Then, **ArrayAdapter class**, internally, inflates provided layout resource view of type `int` to convert to a `view`.

Answer (score 0):

Inflated layouts do become `View` objects, but `R.layout.name_of_the_layout` is an integer identifying which layout to inflate.